# Probability of a palindrome

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, palindrome

$5$ $A$'s and $6$ $B$'s are arranged in a row. Find the probability that a choosen arrangement is palindrome.

I tried out all the ways a palindrome could be formed. This was favourable outcomes.

All possible outcomes were $\frac{11!}{5!6!}$
Probability was favourable upon total outcomes.

What is the alternate way to find out the number of palindromes? I assume it involves selecting gaps from a row and then arranging the alphabets.

Comment: In order to have a palindrome we need an A at the center, 2 As and 3 Bs on the left, and,,,

Answer (score 1):

$6$th place should be A and places $1$ to $5$ uniquely determines places $7$ to $11$, so there are $\dfrac{5!}{3!2!}$ palindromes.